# Engagement history data is stored in salesforce.com or not

Tags: pardot, digital-engagement

We have engagement history enabled and engagement history data is shown in salesforce.com against contacts. I have business requirement to do some processing on this engagement history data.
I want to know if data is stored in Pardot and it is shown in salesforce.com on the fly using lightning component or data is stored in salesforce.com objects itself. i queried task object but could not find activities listed under engagement history for contact.I appreciate help in this regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data shown in the Lightning Component "Engagement History" on the Contact object is actually stored in Pardot's database, not in SFDC.

To process the data, you might need to leverage the [VisitorActivity Pardot API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/pardot/guide/visitor-activities-v4.html) to get access to the records you are interested in.

Comment: thanks for your answer. we want to build our custom scoring model based on engagement history data. would it be best to dump all engagement history data from pardot in a custom sfdc object? actually we want to build the custom scoring model which has scoring in real time similar to what einstien scoring does with standard sfdc.

Comment: I guess you could, just be aware of storage usage